# transform the shape from (X, 1) to (X)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

There is an existing train_labels, which has the following attributes

```
('labels_train shape ', (3000,))
('type of labels_train ', <type 'numpy.ndarray'>)
```

and another array is Y, which has the following attributes

```
('Y ', (3000,1))
('type of Y ', <type 'numpy.ndarray'>)
```

How to assign `Y` to `labels_train`, or how to make `Y` has the same shape as `labels_train`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Can you elaborate your question a little?

Comment: Um, they do have the same shape, according to your output...

Comment: Maybe you are confused by `(3000,)`. This is a tuple, not `(3000, 1)`.

Comment: I have corrected the typo, The current Y is of shape (3000,1), I would like to transform it  to shape(3000, )

Comment: Have you tried `reshape`?  Or indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy over the content from `Y` to `labels_train`, the following should work.

```
labels_train[:] = Y[:,0]
```

If you want to reshape `Y` to have the same shape as `labels_train` (this only works if they have the same number of elements).

```
Y = Y.reshape(labels_train.shape)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  [`squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) function:

```
Y = Y.squeeze()
```

This will remove the singleton dimension so that `Y.shape` is `(3000,)`.